# How to run function when route is loaded?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I just want to have `myFunk()` run when the overview route is loaded onto the page, and when you go somewhere else and come back, `myFunk()` is run again, i have no model for the overview view, i tried to use `didInsertElement` but i dont know if that makes sense.

App.js:

```
App.Router.map( function() {
  this.resource('overview');
});

App.overviewView = Ember.View.extend({
  didInsertElement: function() {
    myFunk();
  }
});
```

index.html:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="application"> 
    <div id="wrapper" class="clearfix">

        <div id="content" class="clearfix">

            {{outlet}}

        </div>

    </div>
</script>
```

And my route template:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="overview">

    <div class="leftBox">
        <img id="kpibox" src="../img/kpis.png" />
    </div>

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could hook into `activate` and `deactivate` correspondently to have your function run when the route enters or exits.

Depending on where your `myFunc()` lives, let's say in the `App.OverviewController` *(but could also be in a different controller)* you do the following:

```
App.OverviewController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  myFunc: function() {
    // do stuff
  }
});

App.OverviewRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  activate: function() {
    this.controllerFor('overview').send('myFunc');
  }
});
```

If you need to pass parameters to your `myFunc()` you include them like so:

```
this.controllerFor('overview').send('myFunc', param);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Seems that activate fires before my overview view is rendered onto the page, is there a way to fire it after the view is loaded?

Comment: @watson, well if your `myFunc` does DOM related stuff then as you already guessed `didInsertElement` is the right place, but if you want your `myFunc` to be in the controller backing up the view, you can get the current controller of the view like this `this.get('controller').send('myFunc');` to fire your `myFunc`